# Pass message between threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I want to send a message from the master process to each thread and print it (yes, in each thread). How can i do it?

I need to send a message from the master to the thread, then print it in the thread and finish it.

I got this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void * thread1()
{
        while(1){
                printf("Hello!!\n");
        }
}

void * thread2()
{
        while(1){
                printf("How are you?\n");
        }
}

int main()
{
        int status;
        pthread_t tid1,tid2;

        pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,thread1,NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread2,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use PostThreadMessage as is explained here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: However you want. There's no "one right way". You can use a queue to each thread. You can use a shared queue and have each thread keep track of which message it's processed last. You can use a file. You can use a pipe. Any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since the main thread and all the sub threads are using the same data,

the main thread places a message in a buffer in the data along with a 'times to print' counter and a message number counter.

```
0) Each sub thread is looping, watching that 'times to print' counter, 
when that counter becomes greater than 0,  then
checks if they have already output that message[number]
if they have NOT output that message then
1) save new message number
2) lock a mutex, 
3) prints the message, 
4) decrements the count of times that message to be printed, 
5) unlocks the mutex. 
branch back to 0)

0) The main thread is looping, waiting for the 'times to print' counter to reach 0. 


when it does reach 0, 
1) set the next message 
2) updates the 'times to print' counter,
3) increment the message number counter
if not all messages sent, then branch back to 0)
```

Of course, the sub threads will need some kind of indication that there will be no more messages, perhaps by the main thread setting the 'times to print' counter to -1

Note: all the sub threads are using the same mutex

It may be necessary to mark the two counters in the data as 'volatile' so the sub threads will retrieve a fresh copy each time.

Suggest each thread have some amount of delay between checks of the 'times to print' counter, so the cpu cycles are not hogged

For best safety, the main thread could also be locking the mutex while updating the message and the counters

Comment: suggest starting each sub thread with a parameter indicating its' number,  then inside the sub thread keep an array where each sub thread keeps any data local to that instance of the sub thread in the array[passed in parameter] entry.